# how to get listboxitem's value on listbox hold event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

xmal code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox2" Margin="0,0" SelectionChanged="listbox2_SelectionChanged" Hold="listbox2_Hold" >

                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle >
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                                <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"  Foreground="White" Text="{Binding NAME}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding PHONE}"></TextBlock>
                                    <Image  Name="c1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0" Source="{Binding IMGS}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" />

                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

class list which is bind to list box is 
  List < contactsclass > contacts = new List < contactsclass >();
PHONE and NAME are getter setter of the contactclass's variables

how can i get this variable's value on hold event of listbox .. i am trying following code

```
 private void listbox2_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

         //contextmenucontact = (contactsclass)(sender as ListBox).DataContext;
           contextmenucontact = (contactsclass)listbox2.SelectedItem;


         MessageBox.Show(contextmenucontact.name);

      }
```

Comment: what version of Windows Phone? 8? 8.1 WinRT or Silverlight?

Comment: windows phone 8.0 silverlight app

Answer (score 0):

if is just the selected item is just use the ToString Function, see this:

```
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string itemText = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            contextmenucontact = new contactsclass();
            contextmenucontact.name = itemText;
            MessageBox.Show(contextmenucontact.name);
        }
```

Comment: sir it is giving error " can not convert string to contactclass" .. how can string convert to object of contactclass .

Comment: it will never go in if statement because selecteditem called only for listbox2_SelectionChanged event not for hold event